# How to get values from a string(irregular)?

Tags: c#, regex, string

For example,
there is a string:

```
dsw900er4.39fsdgkon-55
```

I want to get values(900,4.39,-55)from it.
How can I do it?

Comment: How about you start with `\d+`?

Comment: You need to be more specific in the rules of your regex.  Rather than asking for other people to write a regex for you, why don't you try it yourself?  **Learn then ask, not ask then learn**.

Comment: Here is my regex, but it does not work:[+-]?(\d)+(.(\d)*)?(\s)*

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nI4kT2/4

Answer (score 1):

If by `values` you mean any number then you can try:

`\d+`

which is equivalent to:

`[0-9]+`

[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/mE4wP8/1)'s the breakdown.

Comment: isn't `\d+` equivalent to `[0-9]+`?

Comment: This will not capture the numbers that the OP asked for, like 4.39 or -55.

Comment: @JohnShammas - Check the link it looks matched to me :-)

Comment: @user5723812 I did check the link. "4" and "39" are matched, not "4.39"